How to make specific text bold in the output of my Telegram bot?
I'm working on a Telegram bot and I want to make certain parts of the text bold in the response when providing the profile context of a site. Here’s a snippet of my code that retrieves and formats the site profile:
def get_profile_context(site_name):
    """Find the profile context based on the site name, case-insensitive."""
    site_name = site_name.lower()
    site_info = site_data[site_data['site_name'].str.lower() == site_name]

    if not site_info.empty:
        row = site_info.iloc[0]
        context = (
            f"- Enodeb ID: *{row['enodeb_id']}*\n"
            f"- Site ID: {row['site_id']}\n"
            f"- MC: {row['mc']}\n"
            f"- TAC: {row['tac']}\n"
            f"- Region: {row['region']}\n"
            f"- Regency: {row['regency']}\n"
            f"- Antenna Height: {row['antenna_height']}\n"
            f"- Azimuth: {row['azimuth']}\n"
        )
        print(context)
        global context_global
        context_global = context
        return context
    else:
        return "Site name not found."

async def button(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()

    if query.data == 'profile_site':
        profile_context = get_profile_context(status["site_name"])
        await query.edit_message_text(f"Profile of site '{status['site_name']}':\n{profile_context}")
        keyboard = [
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Back to Menu", callback_data='back_to_menu'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Back to Start", callback_data='start')]
        ]
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
        await query.message.reply_text("What would you like to do next?", reply_markup=reply_markup)


In the output, I want the site name (e.g., "Profile of site 'site_name'") to be bold. However, when I use the * symbols around the text, it doesn't seem to work. How can I properly format this text to make it bold in the message sent by the bot?
i want to the answer is bold :
Profile of site'--':

Enodeb ID: 0000
Site ID: 000000
MC: MC
TAC: 00
Region: NORTH CENTRAL
Regency: city
Antenna Height: 61
Azimuth: 3_0


Try double stars **word** or <b>word</b>.

You'll need to define the parse_mode and then apply bold to the site-name:
await query.edit_message_text(
    text=f"Profile of site *'{status['site_name']}*':\n{profile_context}",
    parse_mode=MarkdownV2
)

